# Inserting a new row in between a set of grouped rows

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how I could, using vba, achieve inserting a new row into a merged and group set of rows. In the screen grab below, I want to insert a new row when a condition matching the name in A4 is satisfied. What is happening is, it is creating a new row, but the grouping of rows and the merged cell is no longer accurate.

```
For Each key In sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker.Keys
    Debug.Print key & "::" & sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker(key)
    sJQL = "project=SISBTXTRPR AND issuetype=sub-task AND cf[12272]  = " & sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker(key) & " order by assignee asc"
    sURL = sJIRAInstance & "/rest/api/latest/search?jql=" & sJQL
    Set JSONObjRemovedTasks = ConnectToJIRA(sURL)

    i = 1
    While i <= JSONObjRemovedTasks("total")

        For Each c In Range("A1:A300")
            If Trim(c.Value) Like JSONObjRemovedTasks("issues")(i)("fields")("assignee")("displayName") Then 
                c.EntireRow.Insert
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = i 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Wend
Next
```

[image]

**TWEAKED CODE THAT FIXED THE ISSUE**

I was able to tweak most of Samuel's code below (full credit to him) and here is what I came up with:

```
For Each key In sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker.Keys
    Debug.Print key & "::" & sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker(key)
    sJQL = "project=SISBTXTRPR AND issuetype=sub-task AND cf[12272]  = " & sRemovedStoriesForTaskTracker(key) & " order by assignee asc"
    sURL = sJIRAInstance & "/rest/api/latest/search?jql=" & sJQL
    Set JSONObjRemovedTasks = ConnectToJIRA(sURL)

    i = 1
    While i <= JSONObjRemovedTasks("total")
        For Each c In Range("A1:A300")
            If Trim(c.Value) Like JSONObjRemovedTasks("issues")(i)("fields")("assignee")("displayName") Then
                MergedCellsRowCount = Range(c.Address).MergeArea.Rows.Count
                Worksheets("Task Tracker").Range("A" & Split(c.Address, "$")(2) + MergedCellsRowCount).EntireRow.Insert
                Worksheets("Task Tracker").Range("A" & Split(c.Address, "$")(2) + MergedCellsRowCount).Offset(0, 2).Value = "Success"
                Worksheets("Task Tracker").Range(Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells((Split(c.Address, "$")(2) + MergedCellsRowCount), 1)).Merge
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
        i = i + 1
    Wend
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have access to your source data and such, I've created a new workbook with default names for all sheets and changed some things to "test" data which returned expected results - I've changed code back to your original with updates to merging the cells.

***(The test code I used is at the end of the answer).***

```
Dim MergedCellsRowCount As Long

For Each c In Range("A1:A300")
    If Trim(c.Value) Like JSONObjRemovedTasks("issues")(i)("fields")("assignee")("displayName") Then 
        c.EntireRow.Insert
        c.Offset(-1, 1).Value = i 'the -1 inserts it to the new row (which is created above the "c.Row"). 
        Range(Cells(c.Row - 1, 1), Cells(c.Row, 1)).Merge
        MergedCellsRowCount = Range(c.Address).MergeArea.Rows.Count
        Range("A" & c.Row & ":A" & c.Row + MergedCellsRowCount - 1).Rows.Ungroup
        Range("A" & c.Row & ":A" & c.Row + MergedCellsRowCount - 1).Rows.Group
        Exit For
    End If
Next c
```

As you've only posted a snippit of your code, I'm not sure if you are referencing any specific sheet or workbook at this code, so I've not specified any sheet objects.

**If you haven't done so already**, you should append the objects and properties in `Range(Cells(c.Row - 1, 1), Cells(c.Row, 2)).Merge` with a `Sheet` object (e.g. `Sheet1` or `Sheets("SheetName")` to prevent unexpected results such as the code referencing the wrong sheet.

For example:

`Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(c.Row - 1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, 2)).Merge`

**OR** you could wrap it in a `With...End` statement like so:

```
With Sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(c.Row - 1, 1), .Cells(c.Row, 1)).Merge`
End With
```

---

Here are some screenshots of the test data and the result of running the code *(see below for the test code used)*:

### Test data:

[image: Sample test data in Sheet1]

### Result:

[image: Result of running code on Sheet1]

**Test code used:**

```
Sub TestInsertNewRowAndMerge()

Dim MergedCellsRowCount As Long

For Each c In Range("A1:A300")
    If Trim(c.Value) Like "test" Then
        c.EntireRow.Insert
        c.Offset(-1, 1).Value = "Success"
        Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(c.Row - 1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, 2)).Merge
        MergedCellsRowCount = Range(c.Address).MergeArea.Rows.Count
        Range("A" & c.Row & ":A" & c.Row + MergedCellsRowCount - 1).Rows.Ungroup
        Range("A" & c.Row & ":A" & c.Row + MergedCellsRowCount - 1).Rows.Group
        Exit For
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I will check this out but right on the outset, in your example, you have only merged A1 values. You have not "grouped" the corresponding (merged) rows as shown in my example. See the '+' icon in my screengrab.

Comment: Noted, sorry I missed that detail. Let me know how testing goes but ill look in to it too.

Comment: I tested the code.I think you got it bang on... almost :) There a couple of observations -  Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(c.Row - 1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, 2)).Merge should be Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(c.Row - 1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, 1)).Merge. The second observation is - for some weird reason, the value is not printing in the newly inserted row. What gives?

Comment: For the grouping, something along the lines of `Range("A" & c.Row & ":A" & c.Row + MergedCellsRowCount - 1).Rows.Group`... you might need to play around with the row references (I don't much use grouping so not sure where it should be for your sheet). 
As for your observations, first one must have been a typo, sorry about that! 2nd one, where does your code output to? Which row?

Comment: Checking this ... EDIT: Where does  "MergedCellsRowCount"  get value from?

Comment: Maybe like this? MergedCellsRowCount= Range("A" & i).MergeArea.Rows.Count

Comment: Yes sorry. Must have copy/pasted the wrong code. Previous comment is spot on. I assigned it as `MergedCellsRowCount = Range(c.Address).MergeArea.Rows.Count` which would be the same outcome as your comment.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to take most of your code and tweak it to my needs. So, what I did was, instead of adding the new row at the begging of the matched row, I added it towards the end of the matched row. In order to get the last row, I got the count of the merged rows. Once I got that, I simply added the new row there. From there on, there was no need to ungroup/re-group the rows (luckily). See my question for the tweaked code. I appreciate you help and I accept your answer.

Comment: Great, good to see it was fairly easy to tweak too (and added bonus for no need to regroup!). I'll leave the answer as is.